# ¿Es más correcto decir "Nos lo pasamos muy bien" o "Nos la pasamos muy bien"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, pronombres, género

Hay muchos resultados en Google para ambas búsquedas. No sé cual es correcto: la o lo.

Comment: Some information here [la pasamos bien](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/la-pasamos-bien.1630703/)

Comment: ¿Te refieres a algún país concreto? En España se usará siempre _pasarlo_, pero por ejemplo en México creo que se estila mucho más _pasarla_.

Comment: Ah ok entonces la diferencia es solo regional y ambos son correctos?

Comment: @fedorqui - Correcto, hasta donde yo sepa, en México se usa *la* en esta frase.

Comment: Muchas veces el nos no se diria. Una fiesta: la, el día, lo, el momento, el encuentro: lo etc. Depende del contexto concreto.

Answer (score 5):

Depende del ***objeto directo*** al que hagas referencia:

**Masculino:**
- ¿Qué tal el fin de semana?
- Nos lo pasamos muy bien

**Femenino:**
- ¿Como pasaron la primavera?
- Nos la pasamos muy bien

Answer (score 3):

Ambas son correctas debido a que son contracciones por omisión

> ¡Nos la pasamos muy bien! (la noche)
>
> ¡Nos lo pasamos muy bien! (el día)

Pese a que no coincidan con el género, el uso de la idea se homologó en diferentes regiones, dependiendo de la popularidad del uso.

Pero también se puede especificar en masculino o femenino dependiendo de a qué se hace referencia.

Answer (score 3):

Soy de Colombia y una amiga estadounidense me acaba de hacer la misma pregunta y me dijo que una amiga española le dijo que es "LO pasamos bien", porque hace referencia "al tiempo" (Yo lo entiendo como "EL momento"), mientras que amigos mejicanos le dijeron que es "LA pasamos bien", pero sin indicar el porqué.

Le dije que aquí en Colombia se acostumbra decir "LA pasamos bien" y será haciendo referencia a "LA actividad desarrollada", que puede ser de género masculino o femenino, pero igual decimos "LA pasamos ..." Da igual que nos pregunten "¿Cómo estuvo la fiesta?" o "¿Cómo estuvo el evento?" ... indistintamente diremos "LA pasamos bien" (Aunque nuestro cantante Juanes diría "La pasamos una chimba, o'me" XD)

Otro asunto es involucrar el verbo disfrutar y ahí sí hablaríamos de "Objeto directo", y diremos que la fiesta "LA disfrutamos", mientras que el evento "LO disfrutamos", pero eso se vería más en los libros. En la vida real, si estuvo bueno, "LA pasamos una chimba !!!"

Saludos desde Locombia.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que ya hay dos respuestas que dicen que depende del complemento directo al que sustituya, yo voy a decir que la diferencia es regional.
En España siempre se dice pasar**lo** bien/mal/como sea.

Como no tengo ni idea del uso en otras regiones voy a suponer que fuera de España si que se puede usar pasarla.

Comment: Alguien me puede echar una mano analizando "lo pasamos bien"? es decir, no sé si el "lo" realmente se refiere a "bien"...

Comment: "Lo/la pasamos bien" could be thought of as "We went through it well."  "We had a good experience."  "We had a good time."  The "lo" has nothing to do with the "bien" here.  It's an object -- it's the object of "pasar."  It refers to the event, which is given in the context, for example, if I pick my son up from a party, I can ask if he had a good time [at the party]: "¿La pasaste bien?"  Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Interesantísima pregunta. Casi habría que hacer otra pregunta aquí en el foro. Coincido contigo en lo del "lo", pero te añado que, tal como yo lo veo, es una construcción que ha devenido en más impersonal que otra cosa. Puedes decir "el viaje lo pasamos muy bien", pero eso significaría algo distinto. Significaría algo así como que "nos lo quitamos de encima bien". En cambio, para expresar que nos divertimos, diríamos una frase diferente: "en el viaje NOS LO pasamos muy bien". Fíjate en que es incluso más larga la frase. Para mí, se ha independizado totalmente de su significado "literal".

Answer (score 1):

Ambas frases son correctas, pero en España la gente dice "nos lo pasamos muy bien", en cambio, en Latinoamérica, la gente dice "nos la pasamos muy bien". De todos modos puedes decir "nos la pasamos muy bien" en España y "nos lo pasamos muy bien" en Latinoamérica, ambos te entenderán.

Answer (score 1):

En México se usan ambas formas. Sin embargo, hay una marcada preferencia hacia el femenino como "la pasamos muy bien" o *pásala bien*. Honestamente como mexicano, tampoco sé por qué. Quizá sea una referencia a *la jornada* o a *la vida*. Así, no es necesario que haya una correspondecia de géneros. Por ejemplo podemos decir:

- ¡Que tengas bonito día! ¡Que la pases bien!
- ¡Pásala bien hoy en tu día!
- ¿Cómo les fue en su primer día? ¡Excelente, la pasamos muy bien!

Si queremos remarcar el hecho de que nos referimos al día en particular, sí es común escuchar:

- ¡Que tengas bonito día! ¡Que lo pases bien!
- ¿Cómo les fue en su primer día? ¡Excelente, lo pasamos muy bien!

Curiosamente, si usamos el pronombre detrás del verbo, no es común usar *pásalo* sino *pásatelo*:

- ¡Que tengas bonito día! ¡Pásatelo bien!

Tomando en cuanta que en otras regiones el uso es distinto, podemos concluir que ninguna de las formas es incorrecta. Sin embargo, dependiendo de la región hay unas formas que son preferidas.

Answer (score 0):

Pensando lo en términos de género es mejor decir “lo pasamos bien” es más correcto ya que es indefinido por lo tanto la pasamos bien es un laismo.Un saludo a ver alguien me lo desmiente.